# What are the definitions of the order statuses? OR: Where should I integrate my order state?

Tags: orders, magento-1, order-status, status, state

I want to define some order states like "credit card payment received", the question is to which statuses they belong. Is there a definition for each of the built-in statuses?

*Edit: Seems like I mixed up "status" and "state", I hope it gets clear from the context anyways. I blame the German Magento translation (State => Status, Status => Zustand)*

Answer (score 45, accepted):

According to "The Definitive Guide to Magento" <sup>[1]</sup>, the order statuses are defined as follows:

> - **Pending:** Pending orders are brand new orders that have not been processed. Typically, these orders need to be invoiced and shipped.
> - **Pending PayPal:** Pending PayPal orders are brand new orders that have not been cleared by PayPal. [...]
> - **Processing:** Processing means that orders have either been invoiced or shipped, but not both.
> - **Complete:** Orders marked as complete have been invoiced and have shipped.
> - **Cancelled:** Cancelled orders should be used if orders are cancelled or if the orders have not been paid for.
> - **Closed:** Closed orders are orders that have had a credit memo assigned to it and the customer has been refunded for their order.
> - **On Hold:** Orders placed on hold must be taken off hold before continuing any further actions.

Therefore a state "credit card payment received" would belong to `processing`, providing that the order has not been shipped yet.

---

Aligent Consulting<sup>[2]</sup> created a flow chart for order states:

[image: magento order state flow]

---

#### Sources:

> 1. Adam McCombs and Robert Banh: "The Definitive Guide to Magento", Apress, 2009 (ISBN    1430272287, 9781430272281)
> 2. https://twitter.com/aligent/status/509487359172177921/photo/1

Comment: I'm all for self-answered questions - but this just seems like low-quality seeding. A copy+paste answer that could otherwise easily be found online doesn't really add much value to this site.

Comment: @sonassi: I respect your opinion and would not claim the question to be top-quality but I searched a while for this and did not find related questions here or on SO yet, so it might help someone else in the future.

Comment: I found this super helpful.

sometimes you find things more easily on stack than on google, since stack is pre-filtered, compared to google, so to speak.

and if it is seeding, so be it. They provided value. I'm totally OK with the seeding.

Answer (score 2):

The different order states are defined in Mage_Sales_Model_Order:

```
const STATE_NEW             = 'new';
const STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT = 'pending_payment';
const STATE_PROCESSING      = 'processing';
const STATE_COMPLETE        = 'complete';
const STATE_CLOSED          = 'closed';
const STATE_CANCELED        = 'canceled';
const STATE_HOLDED          = 'holded';
const STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW  = 'payment_review';
```

Comment: +1 Is this overridable? Is there a way to get this from the rest api? e.g. /config/sales/possibleStatusList?

Comment: Overwrite the constants? Why do you want to overwrite them? You can define new order statuses in backend (System > Order Statuses). If you mean 'change order statuses', yes this is possible. And yes, you can also get the order status from the API (sales_order.info method or sales_order.list method)

Comment: yes i meant change the list not the constants. do you know how i can access sales_order.info in rest api? whats the endpoint? i tried /salesorders/info relative url

Comment: Shouldn't be hard, see here for access in general: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/33187/6291 and infos about sales_order.info here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the SOAP api is really different than REST api. For some reason, I can't find that you talk about in the REST api docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html

Can you see it there? Maybe it's not included in the REST api?

Answer (score 1):

Actually since 1.5 order statuses can be defined in Admin section and xml is not preferred way of adding/changing states or statuses.
Please make a difference between state and status. State is 'processing' status is 'credit card payment received'

**Update**:
Order statuses can be created and modified in admin/sales_order_status/, no need to do anything in XML
You can assign a status only if order is in appropriate state. By default order goes into Processing state when it is invoiced or shipped.

Comment: Was this meant as a comment on Sebastian Lind's answer? As for states and statuses, seems like I mixed them up (again...), thanks for the correction.

Answer (score -1):

You can connect your new state to existing order statuses, or you create completely new. Simply modify the configuration file of the sales module as follows (app \ code \ core \ Mage \ Sales \ etc \ config.xml) with your new state:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <!-- ... -->
  <global>
    <sales>
      <order>
        <statuses>
          <new_status>
            <label>New Status</label>
            <description>Your Description here</description>
          </new_status>
        </statuses>
        <states>
          <new>
            <label>New</label>
            <statuses>
              <new_status/>
            </statuses>
            <visible_on_front/>
          </new>
        </states>
      </order>
    </sales>
  </global>
</config>
```

Refresh the cache, done.

Comment: Nothing about this answer is appropriate, I'm afraid.

Comment: Do not edit the Magento core. Rather create a configuration in your own module. Magento will merge yours and the core's configuration files.