# How to Get core_config_data using Magento soap api?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, api, soap, core-config-data

How to get value of core_config_data eg. `general/region/state_required` using Magento soap api?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create A Custommodule:

Api File(Api.php)

```
 <?php
class Amit_Customapi_Model_Api extends Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract
{        
        public function myregion()
        {
             $countryList = explode(',', Mage::getStoreConfig(general/region/state_required));

        return $countryList;
        }
}
```

and etc/api.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <customapi_api translate="title" module="customapi">
                <title>Myapi</title>
                <acl>customapi/api</acl>
                <model>customapi/api</model>
                <methods>                    
                        <myregion translate="title" module="customapi">
                            <title>Require Region</title>
                            <acl>customapi/myregion</acl>
                        </myregion>
                </methods>
            </customapi_api>
        </resources>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <customapi translate="title" module="customapi">
                    <title>Customapi</title>
                    <sort_order>2000</sort_order>                    
                    <myregion translate="title" module="customapi">
                        <title>Require Region</title>
                    </myregion>
                </customapi>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </api>
</config>
```

You can access by  below url

```
SOAP

$client = new SoapClient('http://yourhost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('******', '******');
$date = $client->call($session, 'customapi_api.myregion');


XML-RPC

$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://yourhost/api/xmlrpc/');
$session = $client->call('login', array('******', '******'));
$date=$client->call('call', array($session, 'customapi_api.myregion'));
```

**Edit:** Full module

```
app/code/local/Amit/Customapi/etc/
File:config.xml and
```

code of this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Amit_Customapi>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Amit_Customapi>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <customapi>
        <class>Amit_Customapi_Helper</class>
      </customapi>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <customapi>
        <class>Amit_Customapi_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>customapi_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </customapi>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks Amit for such a detailed answer. I tried creating custom module as you mention (Also added blank Helper/Data.php and assign role 'Required Region' to user ) but it says 'Access Denied'. I don't know what went wrong

Comment: I need to create helper class.then reset admin permissio

Comment: What I did is created `Helper/Data.php` with `<?php

class Amit_Customapi_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{   
}` But still it says 'Access Denied'. What do you mean by 'RESET admin permisssion'

Comment: If `Webservice - SOAP - Resource Roles` selected to `All` then output is correct, but if `Resource role` selected to `Custom` and checked `Required Region` then output is `Access Denied`. Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: @AmitBera My soap return value as objects how to return as XML? my code : https://justpaste.it/58dm2 can you pls help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

But what you can do is create your own SOAP API callable function/extend SOAP API.

The (current) details are published here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html

Then you can make Magento do what you need.

There may be a module out there already that exposes parts if not the whole of core_config_data but it's unlikely!

The Core Config Data is a odd one to expose on the API as it contains most of the keys to the empire. So if you do extend to get data from here, make sure it's read only and restrict it to a set of keys. Say general/region/*