# Link of order state with Order status

Tags: order-status, order-state

I wanted to confirm what is the link of order status to order state..?
Means if i link multiple Order status to order state e.g. to Processing, what does it mean?

Comment: For order status, see also this answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/516/231

Answer (score 1):

An order state can have multiple order statuses, whereas one order status is the default of one order state.

You can check out the Order States and Statuses here: `System > Order Statuses` as shown in this picture:

[image: Magento CE 1.9.2.0 Order states and statuses]

Standard order status as of Magento CE 1.9.2.0 (see table `sales_order_status`) are:

- Canceled
- Closed
- Complete
- Suspected Fraud
- On Hold
- Payment Review
- PayPal Canceled Reversal
- PayPal Reversed
- Pending
- Pending Payment
- Pending PayPal
- Processing

The order statuses are already explained in detail here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/516/231